# X-Axis zoomable(scroll-zoom) or time interval button JavaScript Charting Library

Tags: charts, jquery

I'd like to create charts with jQuery library. It must have these:

1. Multiple bars and lines (more then 10).
2. Single X-axes but dual Y-axis
3. Stacked columns bars and lines
4. X-Axis time series
5. X-Axis zoomable (scroll-zoom) or time interval button

like this

[image]

6. Export to pdf or png or share by link

It will mainly used for accounting displays, already can make stack bars, but can not stack line at some time, like this:

[image]

Costs: less than 150$.

Comment: I removed the links because our policy is that each question must be understandable by any expert without having to visit additional links. Please feel free to edit your question to add more textual details.